# Foundations vs. Fundamentals vs. Basics

Tags: difference, word-difference

Suppose there are three books

- Foundations of Machine Learning
- Fundamentals of Machine Learning
- Machine Learning Basics or Basics of Machine Learning

What are the difference.

I think basics means elementary things you must know about that field of study, foundations and fundamentals may mean the main principles that the field is built on them. I don't know the difference of these two, maybe fundamentals point to stronger and wider principles, while foundations points to the basic principles!

Comment: Did you look up the words in the dictionary?  Do the definitions imply something different to you?

Comment: If I found these books, I'd rather read their tables of contents, book reviews, or description on their covers (usually found on the back cover) or on websites, and so on, because we can't judge a book by its title (or its cover), really.

Comment: @DamkerngT. In fact, I want to select a name for a book I wrote! however its main title is in Persian but I want to select an English name for it too.

Comment: @Ahmad I kinda knew what you wanted but I didn't want to post something opinion-based as an answer, so I just posted it up there as a comment instead. One fact remains. I wouldn't trust the title much because some people use them almost the same way sometimes. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There is no significant difference in meaning. **foundation** and **fundamentals** come from the latin word **fundare**, meaning to found or lay a base for something. **Basics** is a relatively new (19th century) English word: it comes from greek via the latin word **basis**, which means a base or pedestal.

So all three words convey the meaning of something that you must put in place first before you can build anything else.

Comment: I agree with JavaLatte. You're asking if there's any connotations or differences between these three words in an academic context. It's a fair question, but I don't think there's much difference. I think _Basics_ might sound simpler than its more sophisticated counterparts, so a college textbook might be more likely to use _Foundations_ or _Fundamentals_, while _Basics_ might be used in cases where the author feels that ["For Dummies"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Dummies) isn't quite formal enough, yet wants to make sure that novice readers won't feel intimidated.

Answer (score 2):

A *foundation* is the base on which something is built.  You "build on" a foundation.

Another way to put it: If X and Y are the foundation of Z, X and Y "make" Z.

*Fundamentals* are the basic components used to build something else.  You "build with" fundamentals.

Another way to put it: If X and Y are fundamentals of Z, X and Y "are used in" Z.

Though usually this distinction is not significant.

Answer (score 2):

**Foundation** is what constitutes the genesis of what you are talking about. A book titled "*Foundations of Machine Learning*" would cover the ideas that motivated the creation of this field of computer sciences: the math and the theories.

**Fundamentals** are the parts of the whole that cannot be detached or else it would become a different thing. A book named "*Fundamentals of Machine Learning*" would cover the elemental parts to build a Machine that Learns: algorithms.

**The Basics** of Machine learning would be an introduction to the topic. A book named "*Machine Learning Basics*" would cover examples of basic systems and how to program/code one.

Answer (score 0):

The foundations of a discipline are the principles from which the rest of the discipline is derived.

The fundamentals of a discipline are its essential or most important parts.

The basics of a discipline are its most simple and elementary parts which are to be learned first.