# Math is fundamental?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say

"I believe that math is fundamental to many subjects"

as in math is the foundation or the basic for many other subjects like chemistry and physics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/93696/

Comment: It's fine if you'te American, but [if you're British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+math+is%2Cthat+maths+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20math%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20maths%20is%3B%2Cc0) you'd say *I believe that **maths** is fundamental to many subjects*.

Comment: Grammatically, it's fine. *Math* is common in AmE usage, while *maths* is used in BrE (and possibly elsewhere). Substituting *mathematics* might help the sentence to travel well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I don't know that there's more to say. Yes, that's a perfectly valid sentence.

Comment: If an answer doesn't require enough characters to meet the minimum length, maybe the question should be improved instead of answered. [Please don't feed the bears](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1236/)